# Squid cache_peer setup for DNS issues

Tags: proxy, squid

We currently have 4 squid proxy servers in no specific hierarchy. Some of which are experiencing intermittent DNS issues where we receive the following error:

> "The cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL."

However, if I point my browser to a different proxy server and reload the page, all is OK.

As a fallback for any future DNS issues I would like to configure squid's cache_peer setting to automatically query another proxy server if the hostname cannot be resolved locally.

I have attempted to configure cache_peer as below:

```
cache_peer    1.2.3.4    sibling    8080    0    no-query
cache_peer    1.2.4.4    sibling    8080    0    no-query
cache_peer    1.2.5.4    sibling    8080    0    no-query
```

After a squid -k reconfigure, my cache log shows:

```
Configuring Sibling 1.2.3.4/8080/0
Configuring Sibling 1.2.4.4/8080/0
Configuring Sibling 1.2.5.4/8080/0
```

When I browse to my troublesome URL, I get the same error, and this shows in the access.log:

> 1329952290.176  22100 my.ip.ad.dr TCP_MISS/503 1663 GET http://www.troublesomeUrl.com - DIRECT/www.troublesomeUrl.com
>   text/html

Can anyone help me out with this? Not sure what I'm doing wrong here!